# Kartograph Open Street Maps

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, geojson, svg

I am having a little trouble rendering an svg from some OpenStreetMap data. I downloaded the Sweden transportation data from [here](http://vdstech.com/osm-data.aspx) and this is my json config file:

```
{
    "layers": {
        "roads": {
            "src": "roads.shp",
            "simplify": false
        }
    },
    "export": {
        "width": 800,
        "round": 2
    },
    "bounds": {
        "padding": 0.02,
        "mode": "bbox",
        "data": [377.9582, 59.3031, 378.1233, 59.3731] 
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's just creating a blank svg file. When using the polygons mode and if filtered to say a building it renders fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/) (scroll down to *Adding Shapefile Layers* section), you don't need to name the layer if the source is a shapefile. Maybe this is causing the problem?

```
"layers": {
    "src": "roads.shp"
},
```

I don't think you need to include `"simplify": false`, since it appears that `"simplify"` is only necessary when you want to define the level or algorithm for simplification (*Simplifying Map Features* section in the same link)